# C# not all lines return a value, I am unsure what to do

Tags: c#

My code is bringing up the following error

> Program.Main(string[]) not all code paths return a value

I'm trying to understand what exactly it means, to no avail. The code is meant to import a `.txt` file full of integers, then sort them in ascending order. It's not totally finished, but this is the closest I've gotten for a while:

```
static object Main(string[] args)
{
    //take file
    Console.Write("Please select file: ");
    //take filename/path
    string select = Console.ReadLine();
    Console.Write("File " + select + " Selected, Press any key.");
    Console.ReadLine();
    //take contents
    string[] thefile = File.ReadAllLines(select);
    //generate array size
    int a = 0;
    foreach (string Line in thefile)
    {
        a++;
    }
    //make the list
    List<int> thelist = new List<int>();
    //current value in list to display
    int b = 0;
    foreach (string Line in thefile)
    {
        int current = Convert.ToInt32(thelist[b]);
        thelist.Add(current);
        thelist.Sort();
        Console.WriteLine(thelist[b]);
        b++;
    }
}
```

How can I fix this error?

Comment: if you arent intending to return anything change static object to static void

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The big thing is changing `object` to `void`. `object` means the `Main()` method needs a `return` statement somewhere. `void` means it doesn't have to have one. Make this change, and the code will at least compile.

There's also a problem on this line:

```
int current = Convert.ToInt32(thelist[b]);
```

because nothing was assigned to `thelist[b]` yet. You want this instead:

```
int current = Convert.ToInt32(Line);
```

Now the code should *almost* produce good output. You also need to move the `Sort()` and `WriteLine()` to a separate loop which runs **after** inserting all the integers. Otherwise, the existing loop just outputs the current largest item at each iteration, and is *way* slower than it needs to be because it re-sorts each time.

Finally, the whole thing with the loop to populate the `a` variable is just extra wasted code and CPU. You could get this value from `theFile.Length`, but you don't need to because it's never used.

Put it all together like this:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    //take file
    Console.Write("Please select file: ");
    string select = Console.ReadLine();
    Console.Write("File " + select + " Selected, Press any key.");
    Console.ReadLine();

    //take contents
    string[] thefile = File.ReadAllLines(select);
    List<int> thelist = new List<int>();
    foreach (string Line in thefile)
    {
        int current = Convert.ToInt32(Line);
        thelist.Add(current);
    }

    //write contents
    theList.Sort();
    foreach(int number in thelist)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(number);
    }
}
```

I thought you might also want to see what's possible using newer language features:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.Write("Please enter a file name: ");
    string fileName = Console.ReadLine();

    Console.Write($"File {fileName} selected. Press any key.");
    Console.ReadKey(true);

    var numbers = File.ReadLines(fileName).Select(line => int.Parse(line)).OrderBy(i => i);
    foreach(int number in numbers)
    { 
        Console.WriteLine(number);
    }
}
```

Comment: Man, looking at everything you've suggested I've basically realised that I am not good at this at all. Thank you for going through and going above and beyond to show me where the code just will be an inefficient mess.

Comment: Programming is steep curve. Stick at it. No one starts out knowing how to use every little tidbit. When I think of some of my freshmen coursework, I cringe.

Answer (score 7):

Change

`static object Main(string[] args)`

To

`static void Main(string[] args)`

Your definition is saying the `Main` method will return an `object`, but there are no `return` statements I see.